# Creating a set of uniformly distributed random numbers

Tags: java, random

I have a list of `N` objects.
I would like to insert `X` dummy objects which are randomly placed between the real `N` objects, spaced between (0, N).

So I tried the following code.

```
int[] dummyIndexes = new int[X];
int randomStep = N/X * 2; // *2 because the Mean is N/X/2

Random random = new Random();
int randIdx = 0;

for (int i=0; i < X; i++)
{ 
   randIdx += random.nextInt(randomStep);
   dummyIndexes[i] = randIdx;
}
```

This works alright, although I'm not getting a good distribution all the way to the end of the domain `N`.

What's a better way to do this ?

Comment: It seems to me that if `randomStep` is not == `N` then the resulting random numbers will not be evenly distributed all the way to `N`.

Comment: I think you should do `random.nextInt(randomStep)+1`, otherwise if the result is zero you'll get two or more dummy indices which are actually the same one.

Comment: And, of course, note that if you want to possibly get a value of `N` out, you'd need to specify `N+1` for `nextInt`.

Answer (score 1):

This is will ensure you have one random value between each N/X

```
 randIdx = N * i / X + random.nextInt(N / X) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick (but note that it will newer place anything at N, the largest value will be N-1)

```
    int[] dummyIndexes = new int[X];
    int randomStep = N/X;
    Random random = new Random();
    int randIdx = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < X; i++)
    { 
       randIdx = randomStep * i  + random.nextInt(randomStep);
       dummyIndexes[i] = randIdx;
    }
```